# CLASSIC ASP - Do While / Loop with 3 conditions issue

Tags: loops, asp-classic

I Have a SELECT with:

STATUS -1, 0 and 1.

The SELECT Statment:

```
SQL= "SELECT * FROM MYTABLE ORDER BY STATUS DESC" 
SET MYDB = conn.Execute(SQL)
```

My issue:

Divide the SELECT in two parts with DO WHiLE/LOOP

PART 1:

- "NOT EOF" of course
- ALL STATUS 1 (priority and overule register limit)
- Limit to XX registers (variable - TOTALREG)
- NO STATUS -1

** STATUS 1 is the "Approved" status and can overrule the limit of registers.

I have a classroom with 20 students. (limit of registers)
but I can overbook this and make the class with 21, 22, 23 students - with "STATUS 1" = approved.

If I have only 15 approved - I will complete the limit of registers with the first 5 "STATUS 0" (Waiting for approval).

PART 2:

- the rest of the SELECT

I Got a PARTIAL solution with this:

```
DO WHILE (((NOT MYDB.EOF) AND (CINT(COUNTREG) <= CINT(TOTALREG))) OR ((NOT MYDB.EOF) AND (MYDB("STATUS") > 0 ))) AND ((NOT MYDB.EOF) AND (MYDB("STATUS") > -1 ))
```

- IF we have vacancies: `(NOT MYDB.EOF) AND (CINT(COUNTREG) <= CINT(TOTALREG))`
- IF the register is approved: `(NOT MYDB.EOF) AND (MYDB("STATUS") > 0 )`
- Exclude non-approved registers (status -1): `(NOT MYDB.EOF) AND (MYDB("STATUS") > -1 )`

- COUNTREG = will be incremented for each register inside the LOOP (countreg = countreg + 1)
 - TOTALREG = Is a variable (number of person allowed in the classroom)

Its works with all situation.. but when I don't have registers with STATUS = -1  - I got an error '80020009'

why? any idea?

Comment: I think you are messing up things here. You need to loop through `MYDB `  with `eof` to read all data, and inside the loop, you can get and check the data returned, the `STATUS` field.

Comment: Ola @RicardoPontual obrigado pela ajuda. Isso é uma lista de inscritos, o proprio SELECT ja me traz a lista certinha. o problema é que preciso dividir ela em duas partes..a primeira parte contendo todos os que tiverem sua inscricao APROVADA pelo ADM OU o limite de inscritos da turma em ordem de inscricao. o problema é que o ADM pode aprovar mais gente do que o limite de vagas se quiser. se tiver menos aprovado o sistema preenche as vagas por ordem de inscricao de quem ainda esta "esperando aprovacao". Na tabela 2 fica o resto. Entendo o q vc diz, mas nao queria encher de IFs -

Comment: queria apenas fazer o DO/LOOP e parar qdo encontrasse uma das 3 condicoes - status -1, ou total de registros = vagas e liberar pra todos os aprovados. mas acho q nao tenho escolha.. vai ter q ser na base do IF..

Comment: I can understand, but don't forget you are in Stackoverflow in english :)
If you prefer we can talk here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170546/do-while-asp